# Invalid crash stacktrace or minidump

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I built the Unity project for Android Studio(Google Android project). I opened this in  Android Studio. Includes **Firebase-crash**. Make a test to check the exception. In logs :

```
Error sending crash report
bkz: Server did not receive report: Origin Error message: Invalid crash stacktrace or minidump.
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: I've got the same problem: Unity + native Firebase library. I've reported this bug via this form: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/ I advice you to do the same. That's all we can do at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Eventually I found initial cause of this issue and resolved it.

In the logcat we can see that Firebase initialization comes before Unity. Unity replaces Firebase's instance of `UncaughtExceptionHandler` by it's own. Unity modifies `Throwable` by adding info about Unity's version. And it corrupts stack trace somehow. After this `Throwable` passed to previously registered exception handler (Firebase). And you can see `invalid stacktrace` message.

Here's workaround:

In your first scene add script with this code:

```
void Awake() {
    #if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
    using (AndroidJavaClass helper = new AndroidJavaClass ("com.yourcompany.UncaughtExceptionHelper")) {
        helper.CallStatic ("restore");
    }
    #endif
}
```

Then add this class into your Android Studio project:

**UncaughtExceptionHelper.java**

```
package com.yourcompany;

import android.util.Log;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class UncaughtExceptionHelper {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = UncaughtExceptionHelper.class.getSimpleName();

    public static void restore() {
        try {
            Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();

            if (defaultHandler.getClass().getName().startsWith("com.unity3d.")) {
                for (Field f : defaultHandler.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
                    f.setAccessible(true);

                    Object possibleHandler = f.get(defaultHandler);
                    if (possibleHandler instanceof Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler) {
                        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler((Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler) possibleHandler);

                        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "restore " + possibleHandler + " instead of " + defaultHandler);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            Log.wtf(LOG_TAG, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Build it together and now discover `logcat` output:

```
I FirebaseCrash: FirebaseCrash reporting initialized com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbks@6f785ce
I FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
....
D Unity   :  GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture GL_AMD_performance_monitor GL_AMD_program_binary_Z400 GL_EXT_debug_label GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_EXT_robustness GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV GL_NV_fence GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap GL_OES_fragment_precision_high GL_OES_get_program_binary GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_texture_3D GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_vertex_type_10_10_10_2 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_QCOM_alpha_test GL_QCOM_binning_control GL_QCOM_driver_control GL_QCOM_perfmon_global_mode GL_QCOM_extended_get GL_QCOM_extended_get2 GL_QCOM_tiled_rendering GL_QCOM_writeonly_rendering GL_EXT_sRGB GL_EXT_sRGB_write_control GL_EXT
D Unity   : _texture_sRGB_decode GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture GL_EXT_color_buffer_float GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query
....
I UncaughtExceptionHelper: restore com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbkt@8e448eb instead of com.unity3d.player.g@82cd648
```